# Removing characters from a .csv file that should contain only numbers

Tags: c++, string, csv, character, editing

I currently have a .csv file that should only contain numerical values however there are errors in some columns that mean there is text included. I am wondering what the best way of going about removing these characters would be.

I am looking at using `str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), 'xxxxxxx'), str.end());`. For this I will need to read my data into a string and then remove the alphabet from that string. I am currently doing this like so (I use the '?' as a delimiter because I know there are none in my file).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string Weather_test;
char chars[] = {'A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e','F','f','G','g','H','h','I','i','J','j','K','k','L','l','M','m','N','n','O','o','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','W','w','X','x','Y','y','Z','z'};

int main()
{
    ifstream Weather_test_input;
    Weather_test_input.open("/Users/MyName/Desktop/Weather_test.csv");

    getline(Weather_test_input, Weather_test, '?');

    str.erase(remove(Weather_test.begin(), Weather_test.end(), chars[!eof]), Weather_test.end();

    cout << Weather_test;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this is I don't know what to do around the chars[!eof] part. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's `eof` ? It's not defined on my environnment. BTW your program doesn't compile because `str` is not defined. Did you mean `Weather_test.erase` instead of `str.erase`

Comment: I did mean `Weather_test.erase` instead of `str.erase`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead, together with [`std::isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isalpha). Maybe something like

```
Weather_test.erase(
    remove_if(Weather_test.begin(), Weather_test.end(), std::isalpha),
    Weather_test.end());
```

Comment: Ok. That seems to make good sense. I have just been looking into using remove_if. Do you know which library I need to include to get the remove_if to work? At the moment I am getting an error stating "No matching function to call to 'remove_if'".

Comment: @user1432792 It's in the standard `<algorithm>` header. And you are including the correct header for `std::isalpha` (follow the reference link to see which one)? Can you please provide the *complete* error? It might contain other hints.

Comment: I have included <algorithm> at the top and the error simply says 'No matching function to call to 'remove_if'". That's it. I will take a look at the reference links too.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it. This was the final solution that worked!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string Weather_test;

int main()
{
    ifstream Weather_test_input;
    Weather_test_input.open("/Users/MyName/Desktop/Weather_test.csv");

    getline(Weather_test_input, Weather_test, '?');

    Weather_test.erase(remove_if(Weather_test.begin(), Weather_test.end(), ::isalpha), Weather_test.end());

    cout << Weather_test;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks massively Joachim Pileborg!!!